# Create PHP Class for API

Tags: php

I have created this Class in PHP:

```
class ITL_Mailer{
        public function __construct() {
            $this->api_key = 'test';
            $this->api_salt = 'pass';   
            $this->api_domain = 'domain.com';
        }

        public function build_query($type, $data = array()) {
            $salted = hash_hmac('md5', $this->api_key, $this->api_salt);

            $data['api_key'] = $salted;
            $data['key'] = $this->api_key;
            $params = $data;

            $data_string = json_encode($params);  

            $ch = curl_init($this->api_domain.'/api/' . $type);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                                        'Content-Type: application/json',
                                                        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
                                                    );
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $response = json_decode($response);

            return $response;
        }
    }
```

I am calling it here:

```
$mailer = new ITL_Mailer();
var_dump($mailer->build_query('test'));
```

then my `domain.com/api/test` page currently contains:

```
return $_POST["key"];
```

however, nothing is being returned.

Have I created something incorrectly?

Comment: Examine the `$response` *before* it is passed to `json_decode()`.

Comment: ok, i tried a `var_dump` on that var, and its returning `string(0) "" NULL`

Comment: Could you try to on your `domain.com/api/test` do the following: `return json_encode("result" => $_POST["key"]);`?

Comment: Try to pass the array without JSON encoding: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);`, and `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. Not sure JSON is supported here, as [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) says: *This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like `para1=val1&para2=val2&...` or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value.*